# Python _Ctypes DLL import error windows 10

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, ctypes

I try to build a Conda environment for my project.

I'm using `python 3.12.10`.Packages that have been installed using conda command:

- Pandas
- numpy
- tensorflow v2.10
- transformers

then I tried to test my env I run a title code which import all those pkgs but I have the error bellow, even when I run any `pip` command I thar env. I have reinstalled anaconda but still there.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 5, in <module>

from pip._internal.cli.main import main

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>

from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>

from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>

from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\build_env.py", line 19, in <module>

from pip._internal.cli.spinners import open_spinner

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\spinners.py", line 9, in <module>

from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 29, in <module>

from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 41, in <module>

from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>

from . import _sysconfig

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations\_sysconfig.py", line 11, in <module>

from .base import change_root, get_major_minor_version, is_osx_framework

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations\base.py", line 9, in <module>

from pip._internal.utils import appdirs

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py", line 13, in <module>

from pip._vendor import platformdirs as _appdirs

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\platformdirs\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>

PlatformDirs = _set_platform_dir_class() #: Currently active platform

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\platformdirs\__init__.py", line 26, in _set_platform_dir_class

from pip._vendor.platformdirs.windows import Windows as Result

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\platformdirs\windows.py", line 4, in <module>

import ctypes

File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\st_env\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>

from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: Le module spécifié est introuvable
```

Comment: Translation of the error message: "specified module could not be found"

Comment: @martin Benes i noticed but which package should i install cause i tried to reinstall ctypes as it's the one causing the issue but not worked

Comment: ctypes comes with Python itself, it is part of the standard library

Comment: What's the command list you execute?

Comment: yes i saw that an according with an AI i just ran `conda install -c anaconda libffi` in my conda environment since i don't have python native installed and that fixed the issue @Martin Benes